# How to echo individual css classes for li's?

Tags: php, css, class, echo

```
<ol class="rectangle-list">
<?php
    include('dbconnect.php');

    $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tip_unitate,tip_id FROM tipunitate ORDER BY tip_id ASC");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $pid=$row['tip_id'];
        $unitate=$row['tip_unitate'];
        $count=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COUNT(*) AS num FROM unitate WHERE tip_id='$pid'");
        $rowss = mysqli_fetch_array($count);
        $number=$rowss['num'];
        echo "<li><a href=\"map.php?pid=".$pid."\">".$unitate."(".$number.")</a></li>";

    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
</ol>
```

This is my code. What I need is to assign individual classes to the li's in that OL. There are 8 li's. I've seen a lot of answers about similar questions but could not do it by myself due to my low PHP knowledge.

Comment: If the reason for this is to style each li individually you may want to consider using the nth-child selector in CSS.

Comment: So what is the issue with the code? What errors are thrown, what are the results, etc

Comment: did you mean individual / unique `id`'s instead...? why would you need classes?

Comment: Doing queries in a loop is almost never a good idea. You should probably use a `JOIN` instead. And have you tried anything yourself to add the classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a unique identifier for each `li` tag, the simplest solution is to assign the `$pid` variable as the `id` of the element. So like this:

```
echo '<li id="pid' . $pid . '">...</li>';
```

Then you can assign styles to these elements according to their unique ID's. For example:

```
<style>
#pid1 { ... }
#pid2 { ... }
...
</style>
```

You only need classes for styles shared across multiple elements. In that case, you could do something like this:

```
// array keys should be the PIDs associated with the classes you wish to assign
// define this array outside your loop
$styles = array(
    0 => 'style1',
    8 => 'style8',
);
```

Then inside your loop:

```
echo "<li class=\"{$styles[$pid]}\"><a href=\"map.php?pid={$pid}\">{$unitate}({$number})</a></li>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using CSS for the task at hand?

please have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp 
simple and quick example to be found here http://jsfiddle.net/2r3kxr8g/

```
li:nth-child(2) {
  background: #d70;
  padding: 9px;
}
```

The only thing you must bear in mind is that you should limit the elements you want to style by explicitly defining them in CSS

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do
    echo "".$unitate."(".$number.")";

$i is a counter

Answer (score 0):

I might create a custom function for this, especially if there's going to be the potential for more than 2 or 3 different classes. This way you help maintain the readability of your code and compartmentalize it a bit.

In the example below I used `$pid` as the reference point to determine which class to use. Your actual use case may be different.

```php
function get_li_class( $pid ) {

     switch ( $pid ) :
          case 1:
               return 'apple';
               break;
          case 2:
               return 'house';
               break;
          case 'apple':
               return 'dog';
               break;
          // more and more options if you'd like
          default:
               return ""; // or some other class
               break;
     endswitch;

}

while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
     // your code here
     $class = get_li_class($pid);
     echo '<li class="' . $class . '"><a href="#">...</a></li>';
}
```